# Importing Google Passwords

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently creating an app the stores a sites username, URL, and password in a 2d array.  I currently can not find an API that allows me to import the passwords saved in the google account into the array. Is there a backend way to do this?

Comment: That's pretty insecure, man. I can't imagine Google would allow extension developers to get access to passwords. Besides that, I'd just like to point out that you're actually asking two questions here. Consider making two separate posts!

Answer (score 3):

OF course there isn't.  Do you have any idea how horribly insecure that would be?  Google doesn't even know your password-  it just knows the salted hash of it.

Comment: Then how does LastPass get chromes saved passwords?

Comment: By reading the local file that Chrome wrote..  But it can't get your passwords from Google, and it can't get your password for your google account unless you signed in via chrome using that feature.  And truthfully if you use that feature you're an idiot.

Comment: But no competent website even stores your password.  YOu hash the password (with a per user SALT) and store only the hashed values.  That way if you have a breach, the users passwords cannot possibly be lost.  And with separate SALTs its impossible to decrypt and crack the entire password file at once, you'd have to go one user at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I would have the user sign into their account through my app and ask them if they would like to import there saved sites from chrome?  Just to be more specfic.